# Opening a file that is a part of a project in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When double clicking on a JAVA file that is part of a project, Intellij used to open the whole project, but after reinstalling, it is opening only the file, as you can see:

[image]

File > Open file in project - opens the project.

Couldn't find how to set it to open the whole project as it did before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature introduced in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1: [LightEdit Mode](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/lightedit-mode/?_ga=2.164021692.2044632923.1587489434-1604080390.1557075480)

If you want to disable it, you can try the following suggestion: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-236868#focus=streamItem-27-4068744.0-0